# Scala: Set of tuples doesn't allow me to add a "straight" tuple

Tags: scala, hashmap, set, tuples

I have this code of a mutable Hashmap with a mutable Set with tuples:

```
  val field = mutable.HashMap[String, mutable.Set[(Pos3, Pos3)]]()
```

In foreach loop I'm populating the `field`

```
scanner.combinations(2).foreach(comb => {
  val dist = s"${comb(0).dist(comb(1))}"
  field += (dist -> (field.getOrElse(dist, mutable.Set()) += (comb(0), comb(1))))
}
```

which doesnot compile with message:

```
 found   : aoc2021.Pos3
 required: (aoc2021.Pos3, aoc2021.Pos3)
      field += (dist -> (field.getOrElse(dist, mutable.Set()) += (comb(0), comb(1))))
```

However whenever I change the bare `(comb(0), comb(0))` with a value-referenced tuple:

```
scanner.combinations(2).foreach(comb => {
  val posTuple = (comb(0),comb(1))
  val dist = s"${comb(0).dist(comb(1))}"
  field += (dist -> (field.getOrElse(dist, mutable.Set()) += posTuple))
}
```

It compiles & executes nicely. I also played with (immutable.)Sets: same story.
PS I know I should use idiomatic scala and ditch the side effects and foreach.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks! leaves the question why the argument parentheses is not needed for the referenced value posTuple?

Comment: @drjerry context - one uses `(x, y)` before assignment so it can only be a tuple, the other uses `(x, y)` in context of function call where the outermost parenthesis are assumed to contain arguments of a function/method (operator `+=` is still a method).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez makes sense! Thanks! If you convert your comments into an answer I can properly award it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you do `foo += x` that is just sugar syntax for `foo.+=(x)` *(i.e. omit the dot and the parenthesis)*
But when you do `foo += (x, y)` the compiler thinks you are just omitting the dot instead of passing a tuple which produces the error you were seeing.

The solution would be to use a double set of parenthesis like: `((comb(0), comb(1)))` or using the `->` extension method like: `(comb(0) -> comb(1))`

---

*This is among the innumerable amount of reasons why I dislike the excessive amount of sugar syntax that the language allows*.